# SQL query using a date field to ensure I use my index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with **date** column named **day**. The way I have it indexed is using multiple keys:

**KEY user_id (user_id,day)**

I want to make sure I use the index properly when I make a query that selects `every row for a user_id from the beginning of the month to a given day in the month`. For example, let's say I want to query for every day since the beginning of the month until today, what's the best way to write my query to ensure that I hit the index, here's what I have so far:

```
select * from table_name 
WHERE user_id = 1
AND (day between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
```

Comment: MySQL reads multi-part indexes from left to right, so your query will hit the index. However, because you are doing a `range` comparison, the query behavior is a little different. More informaton: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html

Comment: You can use the EXPLAIN command to determine if mysql uses the index or not.

Answer (score 0):

use **Explain** to ensure if your query using the index you've created

For example

```
explain 
select * from table_name 
WHERE user_id = 1
AND (day between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
```

should give you the details of the **query plan** by the mysql optimizer

In the query plan in **possible keys** there **user_id**(index) should be present --- > which states that the possible indexes that can be used to fetch the result set from a particular table

**keys** field **user_id**(index) should be present --- > which shows that the index that is being used to get the results

**Extra** ---> Additional information  (using index--the whole result set can be fetched from the index file itself, using where ---> query uses index for filter the criteria and so on...)

In Your query you have mentioned **user_id = 1** constant which will help more in reducing the number of records that are to be scanned, even though there is a range check on **day**, so the query will use index provided that you have less percentage of duplicate values in **user_id** column

Comment: Why not ask him for a schema and explain output, and see it thru.

Comment: You'll need `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to see if it really included `day`.

Comment: Your KEY should work.  But, beware:  The statistics (cardinality) may say that it is not worth using the index.